# IE11 with Vue-Cli project: Script1002: Syntax Error

Tags: vuejs2, internet-explorer-11, vue-cli-3

My app works great in Chrome/Firefox/Edge, but IE11 giving me some issues. When testing the app on my localhost, I get the following error in IE11 in console:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
app.js (49143, 1)
```

When I click the above code, it jumps to this part of my code as the possible error area:

```
"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "default", function() { return Config; });
class Config { <---this is line 49143

    constructor() {
    this.config = {}
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      Object.assign(this.config, arguments[i])
        }
    }
```

I'm guessing IE11 is having trouble with ES6 or something. Is my project not configured correctly for IE11?

> My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --report --modern",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.18",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.6",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.20",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jso": "^4.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-matomo": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-popperjs": "^1.6.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

> Babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/app']
}
```

> .browserslistrc

```
> 1%
last 2 versions
not ie <= 8
```

Thanks for any tips you can provide!

**Update:** Possibly babel-transpiler issue?

Here is my demo code. As you can see, doens't work in IE11:
**https://codesandbox.io/embed/bootstrapvue-table-assigness-and-checkbox-final-h5vst**

Comment: You can try to configure babel to point ES 5 like mentioned in the answer for this thread. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881807/compiling-es6-and-vue-js-not-working-in-ie-11/52882447

Answer (score 2):

Last time I had to deal with such error, I came to the following solution:

> babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  const config = {
    "presets": [
      ["@babel/env", {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 4 versions",
            "IE 11"
          ]
        }
      }],
      // "@babel/stage-0"
    ],
    plugins: [
      // Stage 0
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind",

      // Stage 1
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators",
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining", {"loose": false}],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator", {"proposal": "minimal"}],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator", {"loose": false}],
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions",

      // Stage 2
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",

      // Stage 3
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {"loose": false}],
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
      ["transform-es2015-template-literals", {
        // "loose": true,
        "spec": true
      }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
        "helpers": false,
        "regenerator": true
      }]
    ],
  };
  return config;
};
```

ofc, all those babel plugins should be installed as devDependencies.

Comment: no results for me, sorry